# Как создать окно без полей, которое можно перетаскивать

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Я очень много не понимаю, так как я новенький в программировании. У меня проблема в том что я сделал окно без рамок, и хочю чтобы его можно было перетаскивать. 
Но в итоге окно есть без рамок, но не перетягивается.

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(171, 122)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.old_pos = None

        self.Clicker = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Clicker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 171, 121))
        self.Clicker.setText("")
        self.Clicker.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Interface/2.jpg"))
        self.Clicker.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Clicker.setObjectName("Clicker")
        self.Status = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 61, 61))
        self.Status.setText("")
        self.Status.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Interface/4.jpg"))
        self.Status.setObjectName("Status")
        self.Numb = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Numb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 81, 101))
        self.Numb.setStyleSheet("color:#f00;\n"
"font: 87 45pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.Numb.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Numb.setObjectName("Numb")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.Numb.setText(_translate("Form", "01"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer**. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Класс `class Ui_Form(object)` - это `object`, а не виджет `QWidget`. в котором есть методы `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(171, 122)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.Clicker = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Clicker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 171, 121))
        self.Clicker.setText("")
        self.Clicker.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Interface/2.jpg"))
        self.Clicker.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Clicker.setObjectName("Clicker")
        self.Status = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 61, 61))
        self.Status.setText("")
        self.Status.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Interface/4.jpg"))
        self.Status.setObjectName("Status")
        self.Numb = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Numb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 81, 101))
        self.Numb.setStyleSheet("color:#f00;\n"
"font: 87 45pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.Numb.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Numb.setObjectName("Numb")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.Numb.setText(_translate("Form", "01"))
        
        
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.old_pos = None
        
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_Form()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MDofer если вам что-то еще не понятно - спросите.

Comment: @MDofer я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @MDofer Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: спасибо, очень помогло